# Rails, how to migrate data from development sqlite3 database to production MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration

With Rails, how do you migrate data from development sqlite3 database to production MySQL database?

How to make it easier?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use a gem like [YamlDB](https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db). Install the Gem and then use the following rake tasks

```
rake db:data:dump  
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:data:load
```

The first command dumps the contents of dev database to a file called `db/data.yml`

Also, please remember that this must be used in addition to `rake db:schema:dump|load` tasks as this only ports the data assuming the schema is already in place

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database configurations are properly set up in config/database.yml, the following should get the database structure set up in production for you.

Runs against development database by default:

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Run this against your production database by virtue of the RAILS_ENV environment variable:

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```

Comment: It only creates tables, but how to transfer data from these tables?

Comment: And I think It is same that rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production.