# Archiving Data in Different Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make an archive system of my app with separate app and database?

app1 to app 2 (archive system, the same app different database)
it is like passing the database to give more space to the app1. 
App2 will be only for viewing.

Comment: Take a look at this gem: https://github.com/winton/acts_as_archive

Comment: acts_as_archive won't migrate data between databases, it appears to just store data in different tables. Doesn't appear to be actively maintained.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'passing the database to give more space to app1'?  How does moving the data to another database give the original app more space?  And can't you simply change the database name?

Comment: @PinnyM This is to reduce database query for app1. Transferring data to app2 to provide a viewing page while app1 wll do the input and view at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has some good suggestions: [Rails, how to migrate data from development sqlite3 database to production MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291381/rails-how-to-migrate-data-from-development-sqlite3-database-to-production-mysql)

rake db:schema:dump / db:schema:load will allow you to re-use your current schema, and then yamlDB gem discussed in the above link should help you migrate data.

Comment: I'm actually talking about data copy/transfer from app1 to app2 to lessen the dbase of app1 for faster querying. App2 will be for viewing.

Comment: Is this a one time migration? Assuming you're using the same database vendor for both apps you can do a vendor specific data dump / load to move data. The above linked method converts data to yaml which allows you to use ruby to load / dump the data so that you can move data between databases from different vendors.

Comment: @Puhize How can I do that? Can you please give me a tutorial about it?

Comment: Check out the yamldb gem mentioned in the above link: https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

The gem allows data to be serialized into YAML which can then be loaded into another database.