# Categories and subcategories do not seem to exist in database on Heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my Rails application to Heroku but the categories and subcategories do not exist anymore.

I have categories and subcategories that display on the homepage but after deploying the categories and subcategories do not display. When I run the application locally the categories and subcategories display.

Before when I tried to deploy my app to Heroku I received errors relating to the categories and subcategories. To solve my previous error I put the categories and subcategories in an if statement:

```
<% if Category.exists?(id) %>
<% end %>
```

To me the problem seems to be that the categories exist in my database on my local server but not on the Heroku server.

Comment: Please take care to share only the relevant code when you ask a question here. Most of the code in your question is entirely irrelevant. See [ask]. We'd like a [mcve], with emphasis on _minimal_.

Comment: Chris answered you question, but I’ll also give some advice. In your categories controller, you are not ordering your query, meanwhile you’re extracting records by index. Add `.order(:id)` to `Category.all`. Right now you’re relying on the fact that the database is returning the records in the order you expect, but you aren’t asking for them to be ordered in any particular way. This is a gamble and there is no guarantee that your unordered query will continue to return results in the order you expect (especially as records get inserted and deleted from disk, even in other tables).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I cleaned up your question a bit, as @Chris mentioned most of it wasn't really necessary. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To me the problem seems to be that the categories exist in my database on my local server but not on the Heroku server.

That's how it's supposed to work.

Your local database and your Heroku database are entirely separate. You need to migrate them separately (e.g. `rails db:migrate` and `heroku run rails db:migrate`) and you need to *populate* them separately. Your data doesn't magically copy itself to Heroku.

If you want to copy all of your local data to your Heroku database you can do it using something like [`heroku pg:backups restore`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import), but this requires a *PostgreSQL* backup. It looks like you're using SQLite locally.

Another option is to [dump your local data to a serialized format like YAML and load that data into your remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7291381/354577).

But this shouldn't be something you do all the time. You can easily run into data issues (e.g. duplicate IDs) when you're updating data in multiple places. Accept that your databases are separate. Each copy of your application has different data. That's actually a good thing.

As a general rule I *strongly* urge you to use the same database server locally as you do in production. PostgreSQL and SQLite aren't drop-in replacements for one another. You don't want to discover issues when you deploy code to production.

Comment: Man, that point about using the same database server in all environments is so true. As much as ActiveRecord tries to be universal, there are still subtle (and not so subtle) differences between databases. I wish more people knew this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I solved my problem by running `heroku run rails db:seed`.